# AWS API-gateway - changing response structure

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I have an AWS Serverless application.

When a request arrives it is sent (by swagger configuration) to a custom authorization lambda.

```
securitySchemes:
    my-authorizer:
      type: apiKey
      name: someName
      in: header
      x-amazon-apigateway-authtype: custom
      x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer:
        type: token
        authorizerCredentials: ${authorizerCredentials}
        authorizerUri: ${authorizerUri}
```

The authorization lambda returns a policy to indicate if user allowed or denied.

When it is denied i get back this message:

```
{"Message":"User is not authorized to access this resource with an explicit deny"}
```

My application is running inside a frontend framework that assume all keys are lower case.

Let's assume this is a requirement that can't be changed.

Do i have any way, from within my application (by code or configuration), to affect the response structure so it will be:

```
{"message":"User is not authorized to access this resource with an explicit deny"}
```

Answer (score 1):

This was successfully done by this configuration at the swagger yml root level

```
x-amazon-apigateway-gateway-responses:
  DEFAULT_4XX:
    responseTemplates:
      application/json: "{\"message\":\"User is not authorized to access this resource with an explicit deny\"}"
```